# Is it practical to have a wooden floor installed in an apt in India?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

I own a house in India. It is on the 3rd floor of an apartment.

The floor of the apartment is all concrete with tiles on it.

Having lived in the US for a few years now, I have come to like the feel of wooden floors.

Is it at all possible for me to have wooden flooring laid out in the apt in India?

Note: The temperature there is about 35-42 degrees centigrade (95-108 degrees Fahrenheit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can install a laminate, engineered hardwood, or solid hardwood floor, though solid hardwood expands more and may have trouble with the high heat and/or temperature differentials. Either way, you should acclimatise the flooring by leaving it in the box, in the room where it will be installed for at least a couple days (and a week or two for solid hardwood), before you open the box and install it. If you don't do this, you're likely to have warped boards and/or gaps within a couple days after you install it, effectively ruining the new floor.

You may or may not want to pull up the tiles, as adding another floor on top will add to the height (think of clearance below doors). Height of course depends on what product you choose: laminate can be as thin as 8mm, solid hardwood is usually 3/4".

Answer (score 10):

Humidity is more likely to be a problem than temperature - constant high temperature is OK, it's temperature changes that are an issue.

Hardwood floors are nice and warm when it's cold - you might want a think about why cold stone tiles are popular there